# Separate query from body in Axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, request, axios

In my code, I try to make a PUT request to the applications backend using Axios. The problem originated when the method that is in the user service that handles that request returned a response of null. Here is the method.

```
async idupdate (request, response)
{
    const {_id} = request.query;
    const {name = "", email = "", MACs = []} = request.body;
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate (_id, {name, email, MACs}, {new: true});
    return response.json (user);
}
```

By using a console.log (response), I found out that what was being sent to the was the following.

```
body: {
params: { _id: '5eaa0d719bb04972b07920dd' },
name: 'a',
email: 'a@gmail.com',
MACs: [ '123', '456', '789' ] }
```

The method that makes the request is as follows.

```
const response = await api.put
(
    "/useridupdate",
    {
        params:
        {
            _id
        },
        name,
        email,
        MACs
    }
);
```

My question revolves around the fact that, in a request like this one...

```
const response = await api.put
(
    "/useridupdate",
    {
        params:
        {
            _id
        }
    }
);
```

... the id can be found in the query of the request. I imagine, therefore, that the mistake is in the way I write parameters of the request. For now, I just changed my code so that the method looks for the id in the body.params. I know I can send such id in the "path" of the request, but, because of standardization, I'd rather not. However, if that is the only way, I'll do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST/PUT method of axios has this format: `axios.put(url[, data[, config]])`, so the body goes to the second parameter and query params goes to the third parameter.

For example:

```
axios.put(`api/user`, { name: 'John Doe' }, { params: {
  id: 1
}})
```

Comment: thank you very much. Next time I sit down to code, I'll try your answer. As it's something I have not tried before and, you know, has just been given as an answer to my question, I assume it will work.